How to get APK approve when implement read contact list from device?
My application not approve when get contact from contact list. used this method for access contact list from mobile device.
try
{
    ContractEntity objContractEntity1 = new ContractEntity();
    var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
    ContentResolver cr = BaseContext.ContentResolver;
    string[] projection = {ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoId};
    ShareActivity.contactList = new List<ContractEntity>();
    var cursor = context.ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null,null);
    var emailCur = cr.Query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (emailCur != null && emailCur.MoveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            ContractEntity objContractEntity = new ContractEntity();
            objContractEntity.contactId =
                    emailCur.GetLong
                            (emailCur.GetColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.ContactId));
            objContractEntity.EmailAddress = Constant.Instance().Other +

                    emailCur.GetString(emailCur.GetColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Address));
            objContractEntity.PhotoId = emailCur.GetLong
                    ( emailCur.GetColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.PhotoId));
            objContractEntity.DisplayName = emailCur.GetString
                    (emailCur.GetColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName));
            ShareActivity.contactList.Add(objContractEntity);
        } while (emailCur.MoveToNext());
    }
    context.itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ContactGroup>();
    if (ShareActivity.contactList.Count > 0)
        context.itemsSource = ContactGroup.CreateGroups(
                ShareActivity.contactList.Distinct().ToList(), true);}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.Message.ToString();
}


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"/>


I applied all above code and resolve this isssue but when live to play store then getting error like your application not approve. What I can do to approved by google play store to live my apk on play store.

What specific reason did they give for rejecting your app?

Issue found:
Invalid Data safety form
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.
We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
APK 147: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Contacts Data Type - Contacts
APK 147: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address
About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy

This is pretty self explanatory.  You need to disclose that you are collecting contact info in the Data Safety form.

"Thanks, Jason! I appreciate your suggestion. I’ve already ensured that my app’s data collection practices, including access to contacts, are accurately disclosed in the Data Safety form on the Google Play Console. This includes detailing how the contact information is used, shared, and protected in compliance with Google Play’s requirements. I’ve also updated the privacy policy to reflect these data collection practices to ensure full transparency. If there’s anything specific you think I should add or modify, I’d love to hear your thoughts!"

you need to contact Google and ask for more info about the problem
